# MicrosoftWebDriver for selenium throwing handshake error

Tags: java, maven, selenium, automation, microsoft-edge

**Environment**:

- Windows 10 Build:  16299.251
- Microsoft WebDriver Version: 16299
- Selenium Version: 3.0.1

My testing environment works fine for the latest version of chrome. As soon as I pass in the driver for Microsoft Edge I receive the following error. I am using the following code to connect to the driver and launch the driver which works fine on chrome. If I try to upgrade to the latest version of selenium I get another error which led me to add Guava as dependency in my POM, Guava did not let me update to the latest selenium if that's even my issue for launching Edge.

```
else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("edge")) {
                Log.info("matched name");
                if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("mac")) {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "./src/main/resources/testdriver/MicrosoftWebDriver");
                } else {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver",
                            "./src/main/resources/testdriver/MicrosoftWebDriver.exe");
                }
                localDriver = new EdgeDriver();
                localDriver.manage().window().maximize();
                browserType = "edge";
            }
```

**Exception**

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=, platform=WINDOWS}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'IDME-964HWZ1', ip: '10.9.15.19', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_161'
Driver info: driver.version: EdgeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:128) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:141) ~[selenium-remote-driver-3.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:152) ~[selenium-edge-driver-3.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:141) ~[selenium-edge-driver-3.0.1.jar:?]
    at org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver.<init>(EdgeDriver.java:98) ~[selenium-edge-driver-3.0.1.jar:?]
    at com.webpacs.utils.LocalBrowserManager.initializeDriver(LocalBrowserManager.java:62) [classes/:?]
    at com.webpacs.utils.DefaultWebDriverSupplier.newWebDriver(DefaultWebDriverSupplier.java:46) [classes/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at fitnesse.slim.fixtureInteraction.DefaultInteraction.methodInvoke(DefaultInteraction.java:81) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.MethodExecutor.callMethod(MethodExecutor.java:57) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.MethodExecutor.invokeMethod(MethodExecutor.java:38) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.MethodExecutor.findAndInvoke(MethodExecutor.java:72) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.LibraryMethodExecutor.execute(LibraryMethodExecutor.java:18) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.StatementExecutor.getMethodExecutionResult(StatementExecutor.java:135) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.StatementExecutor.callAndAssign(StatementExecutor.java:118) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.instructions.CallAndAssignInstruction.executeInternal(CallAndAssignInstruction.java:38) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.instructions.Instruction.execute(Instruction.java:29) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor$Executive.executeStatement(ListExecutor.java:49) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor$Executive.executeStatements(ListExecutor.java:43) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.ListExecutor.execute(ListExecutor.java:85) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.executeInstructions(SlimServer.java:84) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.processOneSetOfInstructions(SlimServer.java:77) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.tryProcessInstructions(SlimServer.java:64) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimServer.serve(SlimServer.java:49) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.handle(SlimService.java:154) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.acceptOne(SlimService.java:162) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.accept(SlimService.java:124) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.startWithFactory(SlimService.java:76) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
    at fitnesse.slim.SlimService.main(SlimService.java:56) [fitnesse-20151230.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue was related to the version of Google Gauva. I had duplicate dependencies of Google Gauva in my POM. One of version 13 and one of version 23. After removing the dependency of version 13. Selenium version 3.8.x works fine. The Fluent Wait errors also were removed.

Hope this helps anyone to double check there POM file or dependency file to make sure you have the correct version of Google Gauva. I am using Google Gauva version 23 with selenium 3.8.x on the latest version of chrome with the appropriate web driver for selenium.

If you see similiar errors after upgrading from version 3.0 of selenium to a 3.5 or higher , update your google Gauva dependency to the latest , a library which selenium uses.